# Nodeos dont sync after importing snapshot

Tags: nodeos, full-node

Pls help me)
Im trying to deploy nodeos, but after snapshot import (from this https://snapshots-main.eossweden.org/) node dont receive next blocks. Tell me please what am I doing wrong.

docker-compose file

```
services:
  eos_mainnet:
    container_name: eos_mainnet
    image: eos
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
    command: nodeos
      -e -p eosio
      --http-server-address 0.0.0.0:8888
      --data-dir /root/eos/data
      --snapshots-dir shpdata
      --snapshot /root/eos/shpdata/snapshot-171111279.bin
      --config-dir /root/.local/share/eosio/nodeos/conf
      --chain-state-db-size-mb 65536
      --plugin eosio::producer_plugin      
      --plugin eosio::chain_plugin         
      --plugin eosio::http_plugin          
      --plugin eosio::state_history_plugin 
      --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin
      --plugin eosio::db_size_api_plugin
      --contracts-console   
      --disable-replay-opts 
      --access-control-allow-origin='*' 
      --http-validate-host=false        
      --verbose-http-errors             
      --trace-history              
      --chain-state-history
```

container logs

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add some p2p addresses.  Pick a few from here: https://validate.eosnation.io/eos/reports/config.html

Comment: Thank you so much